# Using Python Ctypes to pass struct pointer to a DLL function

Tags: python, pointers, struct, ctypes

I am attempting to access a function in a DLL file using Python ctypes.  The provided function description is below.

```
Prototype: Picam_ConnectDemoCamera( PicamModel model,
                                    const pichar* serial_number,
                                    PicamCameraID* id )

Description: Virtually connects the software-simulated 'model' with 'serial_number'
and returns the camera id in `_id_`
Notes: `_id_` is optional and can be null
```

The function references a few variable types defined in the DLL.  These variables are described next

```
PicamModel
Type: enum
Description: The camera model.

PicamCameraID
Type: Struct
- PicamModel model: _model_ is the camera model
- PicamComputerInterface computer_interface: computer_interface is the method of
communication
- pichar sensor_name [PicamStringSize_SensorName]: sensor_name contains the name of
the sensor in the camera
- pichar serial_number [PicamStringSize_SerialNumber]: serial_number contains the
unique serial number of the camera
```

Note that'pichar' is defined in one of the provided header files as follows:

```
typedef          char   pichar; /* character native to platform
```

This seems straightforward, but isn't working out for me for some reason.

My understanding is as follows: I pass the function three variables:

1)  a `model`, which is really an `enum`.  I'm told that python ctypes doesn't inherently support enums, and so I am passing it an integer, 2, which maps to a particular model type.

2) a pointer to a serial number (I can make this up: an arbitrary string)

3)  A pointer to `PicamCameraID`, a variable type defined within the DLL, based on the `struct` type

After reading through SO I found a few good starting points, but am still running out of luck.  Here's my best shot so far

```
def pointer(x):
      PointerToType = ctypes.POINTER(type(x))
      ptr = ctypes.cast(ctypes.addressof(x), PointerToType)
      return ptr

class PicamCameraID(ctypes.Structure):
      pass
PicamCameraID._fields_=[("model",ctypes.c_int),
                    ("computer_interface",ctypes.c_int),
                    ("sensor_name",ctypes.c_char_p),
                    ("serial_number",ctypes.c_char_p)]

myid = PicamCameraID()
model = ctypes.c_int(2)
serialnum = ctypes.c_char_p('asdf')
print picam.Picam_ConnectDemoCamera(model, pointer(serialnum), ctypes.byref(myid))
```

As you can hopefully see, I'm trying to create the variable type that corresponds to the `PicamCameraID` struct defined in the DLL.  My intuition was to use the `ctypes.pointer` command to reference this when passing the argument to the function, but I found indications to use `ctypes.byref` instead [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484995/python-ctypes-passing-in-pointer-and-getting-struct-back).

The code runs without error (returns 0), however, I get varying results when I try to access the properties of the struct `PicamCameraID`:

`myid.model` returns "2" which is great that's what I specified
`myid.computer_interface` returns "1" which is fine

**BUT** the problem is `myid.serial_number` returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in
<module>
   myid.serial_number ValueError: invalid string pointer 0x2820303031207820
```

and `myid.sensor_name` returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in
<module>
    myid.sensor_name ValueError: invalid string pointer 0x3034333120563245
```

For some reason these strings aren't being properly populated?

Any ideas would be much appreciated, I am a novice to python ctypes (and c)

Kind regards

Addition June 1 2013

```c
typedef enum PicamStringSize {
    PicamStringSize_SensorName     =  64,
    PicamStringSize_SerialNumber   =  64,
    PicamStringSize_FirmwareName   =  64,
    PicamStringSize_FirmwareDetail = 256 } PicamStringSize; 

typedef struct PicamCameraID {
    PicamModel             model;
    PicamComputerInterface computer_interface;
    pichar                 sensor_name[PicamStringSize_SensorName];
    pichar                 serial_number[PicamStringSize_SerialNumber];
} PicamCameraID;
```

Comment: What is `pichar`? How the size of the string is determined? What happens if you pass `serialnum` directly without the `pointer()` call?

Comment: J.F. -- Thanks for responding.  My header file tells me the following:

typedef          char   pichar; /* character native to platform   

in other words, I belive it is just  re-mapping of char?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definition of PicamCameraID structure is incorrect: `sensor_name` and `serial_number` are [arrays](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-arrays):

```
"""
struct PicamCameraID {
  PicamModel             model;
  PicamComputerInterface computer_interface;
  pichar                 sensor_name[PicamStringSize_SensorName];
  pichar                 serial_number[PicamStringSize_SerialNumber]; 
};
"""
import ctypes as c

PicamStringSize_SensorName = PicamStringSize_SerialNumber = 64
PicamModel = PicamComputerInterface = c.c_int
pichar = c.c_char

class PicamCameraID(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("model", PicamModel),
                ("computer_interface", PicamComputerInterface),
                ("sensor_name", pichar * PicamStringSize_SensorName),
                ("serial_number", pichar * PicamStringSize_SerialNumber)]
```

It seems the second argument is just a string, so you don't need to apply `pointer()` to it. Here's the `ctypes` prototype for `Picam_ConnectDemoCamera()` function:

```
"""
Picam_ConnectDemoCamera(PicamModel model, const pichar* serial_number,
                        PicamCameraID* id)
"""
pichar_p = c.c_char_p # assume '\0'-terminated C strings
Picam_ConnectDemoCamera.argtypes = [PicamModel, pichar_p,
                                    c.POINTER(PicamCameraID)]
Picam_ConnectDemoCamera.restype = c.c_int # assume it returns C int
```

To call it:

```
picam_id = PicamCameraID()
rc = Picam_ConnectDemoCamera(2, "serial number here", c.byref(picam_id))
print(rc)
print(picam_id.sensor_name.value) # C string
print(picam_id.sensor_name.raw)   # raw memory
```

Comment: Thanks J.F. -- this is immensely helpful

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you're not entering the exact structure fields in the exact same order.  If you don't, then you usually get random data or segfaults.  To access a library with ctypes, you usually need to look inside the header (.h file) to copy the exact structure definition.  Alternatively, use [cffi](http://cffi.readthedocs.org/) with ffi.verify() if you don't want to depend on the precise layout.

Comment: Hi Armin -- I just added some text from the header file which I think addresses your suggestion.  Could it be that my 'sensor_name' string is not specified to the correct length and therefore my two strings are essentially getting smushed together and data is lost?

I see that the header file does indeed define a string size for these variables but it is not clear to me how I can account for this string size when i define the variables using ctypes

Comment: You're declaring it wrongly, and ctypes will just use your wrong declarations blindly.  J.F. Sebastian gave a more precise answer.